# $C^0$-approximation by smooth curves with prescribed curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, differential-equations

A theorem by Ghomi (https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10711-007-9151-y) says that any $C^2$ curve $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^{n≥3}$ can be $C^1$-approximated by curves with prescribed *constant* curvature as long as the prescribed curvature is larger than the maximum of the curvature of $\gamma$. I wonder if one could relax the assumption on the prescribed curvature to be constant and weaken the $C^1$-approximability by $C^0$-approximability. More precisely I wonder if the following statement holds true:

Let $\gamma:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^{n≥3}$ be a curve of class $C^2$ with curvature $k$ and let $k':[a,b]\to\mathbb R$ be a smooth function that satisfies $k'>k$ point wise. There is a *smooth* curve $\delta:[a,b]\to\mathbb R^{n≥3}$ with curvature $k'$ that is $C^0$-close to $\gamma$.

I'd be thankful for any reference.

EDIT: I corrected the question, thanks.

Comment: If the prescribed curvature $k'$ is only continuous, then the curve $\delta$ cannot be smooth (by which I mean $C^\infty$) so the answer to the question the way it is stated is: no. Correct your question.

Answer (score 3):

This has been established in a recent paper by Micha Wasem:

[h-principle for curves with prescribed curvature.](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2Fs10711-016-0161-5) 
Geom. Dedicata 184 (2016), 135–142.

In particular Wasem showed that one can prescribe curvature as you suggest, and it is not even necessary to give up $C^1$ closeness.

Comment: Thank you for the reference! In this paper, the approximating curves are of class $C^2$ and I wonder if one could get $C^\infty$ ones (maybe at the expense of giving up $C^1$-closeness).

Comment: @Stadionok:  I think that it should be possible to get $C^\infty$ ones, without giving up $C^1$-closeness.

Comment: This is what I guess too but it is not clear to me, how to adapt your proof...